# Question about MTG card Flamebreak

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was using [Flamebreak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flamebreak) during the MTG pc game, and I had a 5/4 without flying. I used it, and the 5/4 died! Why? It says it only deals 3 dmg to non-flying creatures.

Comment: More information about other things that were on the board required, I think.  All other things being equal, Flamebreak should not kill your 5/4 creature.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear; we cannot provide much more than guesswork with the information provided.

Answer (score 6):

We can't tell why your creature died from the limited information you gave because [Flamebreak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flamebreak) alone would not have killed your creature.

- Maybe your creature's toughness was being buffed by the static ability of [some](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220147) other creature that died from [Flamebreak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flamebreak).
- Maybe your creature already had damage marked on it.
- Maybe your creature received damage from [something](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=266050) soon after [Flamebreak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flamebreak).
- Maybe [something](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=135206) debuffed your creature's toughness.
- Maybe [something](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205268) doubled the damage.
- Maybe ...